# Invalid column name 'warehouse_name'

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-analytics, sql-server-2016

Please assist me to resolve the issue with this query below. It keeps telling me I have an invalid column name. When I run the query without the subqueries and the CASEs and GROUP BY, it gives me a column name correctly.

```sql
`SELECT`
    Warehouse.warehouse_id,
    `CONCAT`(Warehouse.state, ' : ', Warehouse.Warehouse_alias) `AS` warehouse_name,
    `COUNT`(Orders.order_id) AS number_of_orders,
    (`SELECT`
        `COUNT`(*)
        `FROM` Warehouse_Orders_Orders Orders)
        `AS` total_orders,
`CASE`
    `WHEN` `COUNT`(Orders.order_id)/ (`SELECT` `COUNT`(*) `FROM` Warehouse_Orders_Orders Orders) <=0.2
    `THEN` 'fulfilled 0 - 20% of orders'
    `WHEN` COUNT(Orders.order_id)/ (`SELECT` `COUNT`(*) `FROM` Warehouse_Orders_Orders Orders) > 0.2
    `AND` `COUNT`(Orders.order_id)/ (`SELECT` `COUNT`(*) `FROM` Warehouse_Orders_Orders Orders) <=0.6
    `THEN` 'fulfilled 21 - 60% of orders'
    `ELSE` 'fulfilled more than 60% of orders'
    `END AS` fulfillment_summary
`FROM`
    chuks1.dbo.Warehouse_Orders_Warehouse Warehouse
`LEFT JOIN` chuks1.dbo.Warehouse_Orders_Orders Orders
`ON` Orders.warehouse_id = Warehouse.warehouse_id
`GROUP BY`
Warehouse.warehouse_id,
Warehouse.warehouse_name
`HAVING` 
    `COUNT`(Orders.order_id) >0
```

I have tried removing the conditions one after the other. I still can't understand why it keeps saying:

> Invalid column name 'Warehouse_name'

I was expecting to get orders that meet the conditions in the CASEs in the query. I don't know if the problem is the aliases.

Comment: What are all those back ticks scattered in your code? They aren't valid syntax.

Comment: As for the error, you can't group by a column's alias. Repeat the expression or put the columns *used* in the expression in the `GROUP BY`.